# Changing attribute of cloned element

Tags: jquery, ajax, attributes, clone, element

I am trying change attribute of element I cloned, but it just does not seem to work.

My jquery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { note: _note, owner_id: _owner_id, registration_number: _registration_number },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data){
        var tunnus = data.id;
        if(editNoteId == null){
            var firstTableRow = $(".note-table").find("tr").first().clone(true);

            var editLink = $(".edit-note").first().clone(true).data("note-id", id);


            firstTableRow.children("td")[0].removeAttribute("class");
            firstTableRow.children("td")[0].setAttribute("class", tunnus);
            firstTableRow.children("td")[0].innerHTML = data.info;
            firstTableRow.children("td")[1].innerHTML = "timestamp";
            firstTableRow.children("td")[2].innerHTML = data.laatija;
            firstTableRow.children("td")[3] = editLink;

            $(".note-table").prepend(firstTableRow);



        }
```

My elements:

```
<table class="table table--list note-table">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="8038">now</td>
                    <td>timestamp</td>
                    <td>company</td>
                    <td> <a href="#" class="edit-note" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notesModal" data-note-id="8037">Muokkaa</a></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="8037">fug</td>
                    <td>23.6.2016 12:51:29</td>
                    <td>company</td>
                    <td> <a href="#" class="edit-note" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notesModal" data-note-id="8037">Muokkaa</a></td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td class="8036">another</td>
                    <td>23.6.2016 12:45:27</td>
                    <td>avoltus</td>
                    <td> <a href="#" class="edit-note" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notesModal" data-note-id="8036">Muokkaa</a></td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

The editLink will still have same data-note-id as the element which it was cloned from, but  still changes to what it is supposed to

Comment: What is the variable `tunnus`?

Comment: Also, I cannot see `data` defined anywhere so `data.info` would return undefined or an error

Comment: Updated my post, they are both from ajax request

Comment: `attr("data-note-id")` is not the same as `data("note-id")` . The latter is a jQuery convenience that moves all `data-X` attributes to `data("X")` *when the document is loaded*. I'd suggest you read attributes rather than data or update data rather than attributes, don't mix and match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stkLagd3/) of something like what you want
 *(Note, I have used strings instead of the variables (i.e. tunnus) as I did not have access to them)*.

A few things to note:

> `.children`

This will get **ALL** the children of the element you are pointing it at. This method will **NOT** find a specific child element that you desire. To do this, use `.find()` or `.closest()`

*Correction:*

I got mixed up. You are able to select a specific child with `children()` but not the way you were doing it *(using [??] <-- square brackets to get the correct one)(

For example:

```
firstTableRow.children("td")[0].removeClass();
```

...would become...

```
firstTableRow.children("td:nth-child(1)").removeClass();
```

...or...

```
firstTableRow.children("td:first-child").removeClass();
```

> `.setAttribute()`/`.removeAttribute()`

These are useful methods but, for what you are doing, it is better and more readable to use `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`

> `.first()`

I'm not that knowledgeable in this method but just to note that using `:nth-child()` is a more widely used method of getting the child that you want. *(pass an integer into the parentheses to decide which one to get (i.e. 1, 2, 3))*

Also, the last line where you set the element to be `editLink`? By the looks of things, you actually want to set the `data-note-id` attribute of that element and not the whole element. You can use:

```
firstTableRow.find("td:nth-child(4)").data("note-id", editLink);
```

...where the first argument is the `data-*` attribute you are selecting, and the 2nd is what you are setting it's value to